# Calculate emits 'Number of opened and closed parentheses does not match'

Tags: c#, epplus

I have a protected worksheet that the provider will not unlock because it has proprietary formulas.

When I use the worksheet in Excel it works just fine.  However, when I use EPPlus and call calculate it emits an error 'Number of opened and closed parentheses does not match'.  I suspect one of the nested formulas is poorly formatted and Excel is just more tolerant.

Is there a setting to get around this (Like there is for circular references)?
Alternatively a way to scan the whole workbook for which of the nested formulas may be incorrect (so I could get the supplier of the sheet to correct it).

I see there is a module "EPPlus/FormulaParsing/LexicalAnalysis/SyntacticAnalyzer.cs" referenced at https://github.com/antiufo/epplus/blob/master/EPPlus/FormulaParsing/LexicalAnalysis/SyntacticAnalyzer.cs but I can find no examples of how to use this.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you are trying to get around the security that the _owner_ of the file has put in place (for some definition of "owner"). Is that correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Gee, write that there is protection involved and your first thought is I am trying to get around it.  I clearly states it just calculated a different result (Excel calculates, EPPlus throws an error).  I said that so you would not tell me to change the sheet - I can't.  To look at the formula in excel - I can't.

The issue is Excel calculates just fine, EPPlus does not.  The evaluation engines differ and EPPlus throws errors when Excel does not.

The Error message said it was the 'Number of opened and closed parentheses does not match', I later figured it out later it was quotes not parentheses.  The formula was something like =IF(A1="""", 0, 1).

As it turns out despite the protection, EPPlus does let you circumnavigate the protection and read all the formulas.  Thanks for the hint.  And it turns out it also cannot evaluate them correctly (to emulate Excel).  Its rules are different about quotes.  It also has missing formulas (NORMSINV - throws #NAME? error), it fails for circular references that excel does not (when the circular reference is in a VLOOKUP) .  Pretty much it cannot be relied on to calculate a sheet as Excel would yet.